# Delete Hung TCP Sessions with SNMP

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, snmp

What I am trying to do, and failing horribly, is to close a TCP connection... I am trying to do this via SNMP and the functionality that is provided in the TCP MIB.

First, I look at all the connections with SNMP:

`snmpwalk -v2c -cpassword localhost tcpConnState
 TCP-MIB::tcpConnState.192.168.1.1.45328.x.x.94.25.80 = INTEGER: closeWait(8)
 TCP-MIB::tcpConnState.192.168.1.1.54461.x.x.206.25.80 = INTEGER: established(5)
 TCP-MIB::tcpConnState.192.168.1.1.54654.x.x.206.25.80 = INTEGER: established(5)
 TCP-MIB::tcpConnState.192.168.1.1.55123.x.x.206.25.443 = INTEGER: established(5)
 TCP-MIB::tcpConnState.192.168.1.1.60639.x.x.33.168.80 = INTEGER: closeWait(8)`

Just imagine there is a number where the `x`s are above.

So lets say I want to close the first connection, I then enter the following command:

`snmpset -v2c -cpassword localhost tcpConnState.192.168.1.1.45328.x.x.94.25.80 i 12`

I get back the following:

`Error in packet.
Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
Failed object: TCP-MIB::tcpConnState.192.168.1.1.45328.x.x.94.25.80`

I have the correct read/write community string, I have set some other stuff just to test; like the nsCacheTimeouts.  I am getting this on two different machines, my laptop which is Ubuntu and an embedded Linux system, think Debian based also.

Is there some stupid mistake I am making or is there something else that needs to be done before these OIDs can be wrote to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Linux kernel only implements SNMP for statistics. There is no write support for TCP connection objects. For more information, see Linux kernel source tree and e.g. `include/net/snmp.h`.

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I was going crazy...  Would you happen to know if there is a way to view the TCP TCB information?  Now, that I know this is not going to work I want to try and craft a RST packet to close a hung session.  Thanks again!